# mod_rewrite efficient optional parameter handling

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I am building a site with a wide, wide variety of optional $_GET[] parameters: my url can range anything from
`index.php?mod=reg` to
`index.php?mod=complicated&param1=foo` or
`index.php?mod=EvenMoreComplicated&w=4&x=1&y=2&z=3`.

I understand that, in a way, this could be handled with a whole bunch of rewrite rules with an [L] parameter, however, isn't there an easier way to handle this without having to manually specify each possible $_GET[] parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In many frameworks, this issue is tackled by one unique rewrite rule :

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

That means that you get all the query string in one single parameter `$_GET['url']`

Then, [parse_str()](http://en.php.net/parse_str) function in :

`parse_str($_GET['url'], $queryArgs);`

This will give you the $_GET equivalent in $queryArgs.

Also, this is demo code, don't forget sanitization/filtering in real code.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more detail? I've tried this and when I input, for example, `http://localhost/foo/bar` and use `print_r($queryArgs)` I only get `Array ( [foo/bar] => ) 1` without actual values for parameters

Comment: what if you try with what you said in your question : `index.php?mod=complicated&param1=foo or index.php?mod=EvenMoreComplicated&w=4&x=1&y=2&z=`

Comment: `http://localhost/index.php?x=foo&y=bar` returns `Array ( [index_php] => )` in `print_r($queryArgs)` then.